# Profile: Questions, Answers, Comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page

I've decided to look at how many upvotes I have on comments that I made. I can't seem to find it anywhere? Perhaps a tab should be made in the profile just after " Summary | Answers | Questions | Comments " showing your list of comments and upvotes.

Even if there is a way to check your comments that I have not yet found, I still think a tab there wouldn't hurt.

Just a suggestion...

Comment: `api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1681191/comments?sort=votes&min=5` displays all your comments with at least 5 upvotes.

Comment: Comments are second class citizens and are not meant to be permanent so I dont forsee this ever happening.

Comment: [How good is your sql ?](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

Comment: Nevermind I made the query. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this wastes screen real estate and encourages an unhealthy attachment to comments. Anything which encourages "hey why was my comment deleted?" and discourages moving the useful bits into edits or answers as self cleanup is a bad idea.

Comment: One of the best features of Stack Overflow is the ability to delete comments without fuss.

Answer (score 1):

These are all the comments you've made on SO and on Meta with at least one upvote.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/116031